# phpbb forum show category sub category

Tags: php, phpbb3

I want to show category and subcategory in home page like tree structure using phpbb3.

```
Aircraft
    Commercial Aircraft
    Boeing Aircraft
    All Aircraft...
Autos
    Chrysler
    Chevrolet
    All Autos...
```

Here Aircraft and Autos are the category and Commercial Aircraft, Boeing Aircraft are the sub categories of Aircraft. Autos is also same like Aircraft.

Please help me how should I show parent category and all subcategory under the parent category.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the parent of the forum when you create it and you can declare the forum itself to be a forum (with topics) or a category. See https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/ug/quickstart/forums/